# iPhone - reducing file manager access

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I have a method that deletes files. Actually I have this

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:myFile];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];


if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:appFile]) { //I am thinking about removing this line
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:appFile error:nil];   
}
```

as I am trying to reduce the file manager access to a minimum, I am thinking in removing the line that checks for the existence of the file before removing it. Will it be safe? am I risking getting some kind of crash?

I have tested and I had no crash, but who knows...
thanks

Comment: The check is pointless because the file could be deleted by another thread or process between the "exists" and "remove" calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the check for the file to exist without a problem.  You would normally check the return value of removeItemAtPath for YES/NO.  It would return NO if the file didn't exist.  At which point, you would normally check the NSError object for details.